# Debug an obscure error on iPhone

Tags: iphone, c++, ipad

My app crashes on versions 4.2 and 4.3 of iOS. The line of code that crashes is in a C++ library:

```
Ais8_001_22_Circle const *circle = dynamic_cast<Ais8_001_22_Circle const*>(*sa);
```

The console says:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: can't resolve symbol ___dynamic_cast MY_APP 
because dependent dylib #2 could not be loaded

dyld: can't resolve symbol ___dynamic_cast in MY_APP 
because dependent dylib #2 could not be loaded
```

It would probably help if I could figure out what "dylib #2" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to include the lstdc++ linker flag under iOS 4.X

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem. How did you add the lstdc++ linker flag?

Comment: Go to the Build Properties in XCode and add lstdc++ to Other Linker Flags

Answer (score 0):

One possibility - Is the C++ library you are linking to a dynamic library (dylib)?  If so, you'll need find a statically linked version for iOS as iOS does not allow dynamic libraries.

Comment: This bug only occurs on iOS 4.X, not iOS 5.X. Would your answer apply?

Comment: @Andrew - not sure, in that case maybe the library itself was built for iOS 5 which is why it can't be loaded with iOS 4?